# deployment from one change set to another change set

Tags: approval-process

If you see this message , when I am try to  moving approval process from dev to test org it shows:  Approval step sbcgmail.com, which doesn't exist as a user. what is the solution

Comment: Did you try to create this user in your test org?

Answer (score 0):

The user should exist in both the orgs. If the user doesn't exist in the target org then you can choose one of the option to resolve this.

1. Create same user in the target org.
2. Remove that user from approval process and then deploy the approval process.